# If loop cant work in android

Tags: android, if-statement

When I click on Temperature button in 1st activity my second activity get open which has two spinner named as From ad To. I want to give if condition for that spinners but my if loop can't works, loop directly goes to else condition. Please tell mi problem if any or give me solution. Thanks in advance.

```
package com.example.omkar.allinoneconverter;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TemperatureActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Spinner spinner_temperature_from;
    ArrayAdapter adapter_temperature_from;
    Spinner spinner_temperature_to;
    ArrayAdapter adapter_temperature_to;
    String spinner_temperature_from_value;
    String spinner_temperature_to_value;
    Button button_temperature_convert;
    EditText temperature_value;
    TextView result_text_for_temperature;
    String get_temperature_value;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_temperature);

        spinner_temperature_from= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.temperature_from);
        adapter_temperature_from=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.spinner_temperature_from,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter_temperature_from.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner_temperature_from.setAdapter(adapter_temperature_from);


        spinner_temperature_to=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.temperature_to);
        adapter_temperature_to=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.spinner_temperature_to,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter_temperature_to.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner_temperature_to.setAdapter(adapter_temperature_to);


        OnClickOfConvert();
    }

    public  void OnClickOfConvert(){
        temperature_value=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.temperature_value);
        get_temperature_value=temperature_value.getText().toString();
        button_temperature_convert=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_temperature_convert);
        result_text_for_temperature=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.result_text_for_temperature);
        spinner_temperature_from_value=spinner_temperature_from.getSelectedItem().toString();
        spinner_temperature_to_value=spinner_temperature_to.getSelectedItem().toString();
        button_temperature_convert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(spinner_temperature_from_value.equals("Kelvin")&&spinner_temperature_to_value.equals("Kelvin")) {
                    button_temperature_convert.setText("If Works!");
                }
                else{
                    result_text_for_temperature.setText("If Condition Not Working But Else Work's Fine!");
                }
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_temperature, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably some extra space related issue try if condition by using `equalsIgnoreCase` or `contains` method

Comment: Can you post your `spinner_temperature_from` and `spinner_temperature_to` arrays? Maybe there is no value equals to `Kelvin` so this is why you don't reach the *IF* bloc.

Comment: But another options are aslo not working and i copied that string (kelvin) from string. xml